# Graphical environment does not start after update

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I have Ubuntu 18.04 xfce4.14 desktop environment. I am using Compton for desktop effects. I have read many forums about screen tearing in videos, I really have not had such a problem, just a flickering in the windows when I resizing them, I did not like this and I decided to fix it. I assumed it was related to the graphics driver. I have integrated graphics from Intel. I followed a tutorial to update the Intel drivers as follows:

$ sudo add-apt- repository -y ppa: oibaf / graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel

So far so good, I rebooted and didn't really notice any changes except when running the command:
$ xdpyinfo | grep DRI

Shows:
DRI2
DRI3

Prior to the update it showed DRI2 only. Still the windows kept flickering when resizing them. Then the software update application notified me that I had new updates available from that repository and I gave them update. When it finished, without errors, I rebooted and could no longer start my graphical interface. It stayed on black screen

Starter user manager for UID 120

From there it did not happen, then I read that it was incompatibility of AMD drivers with gdm3, I managed to save my desktop following tutorials but the graphic performance was worse than before, when executing the command:

$ inxi -Fxz

In the graphic section:
Driver: vesa (unloaded: modesetting, fbdev)
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128bits)
Version: 3.3 Mesa 20.2.0-devel (git-794334 2020-05-25 bionic-oibaf-ppa)

Before this last update it said:
Driver: i915
OpenGL: Redender: Mesa DRI Intel HD graphics 510 (Skylake GT1)
Version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5

I couldn't go back by uninstalling these drivers as I read in some tutorials. Neither with the command:

$ sudo ppa-purge ppa: oibaf / graphics-drivers --auto-remov

They give me some mistake that I don't remember. Conclusion, I had to re-install to the point where I add the repository and update only xserver-xorg-video-intel.

The question is:
Why if I don't have amdgpu graphics, ATI ..... installed nouveau and all those drivers that damaged my desktop? They have returned to me but I do not plan to update them.
I have solved the problem of window flickering by creating a file named 10-Intel.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ with the content:

Section "Device"
               Identifier "Intel Graphics"
               Driver "Intel"
               Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
               Option "TearFree" "true"
               Option "DRI" "3”
EndSection

After this setup, the glmark2 score was 729. Before it the result was 447. Now the blinks are over, everything feels running much lighter.

Regarding the name of this file, in some forums I have seen that they are named 20-intel.conf and in others 10-intel.conf is there any difference in terms of operation? Without further thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you running 18.04?  The XFCE version you mention is the version found in 19.10 and not older 18.04 (which still had components using GTK2; 4.14 is all GTK3).

Comment: True, I have installed it as indicated here:        https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/csymjx/how_to_install_xfce_414_on_xubuntu_1804/                                          
  I have also updated the Kernel to 5.4. I have not experienced any instability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem here has been the incompatibility that I mentioned above between GDM3 and AMD drivers because I installed lighDM before updating the drivers again and it did not happen again, I have also done it in 20.04 but this time from Xubuntu that already comes with lightDM So I cannot assure you that the problem has been corrected in this release.